# Как прикрепить футер?

Tags: css

Можно ли средствами только `HTML` и `CSS` сделать так, чтобы футер был прикреплен к низу экрана, если контента меньше, чем на разворот, но при этом, чтобы он уползал вниз, если появляется прокрутка (`position: fixed;` не поможет)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно можно: [прижимаем футер к низу](http://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Буду учиться пользоваться поиском)