# Стили футера в зависимости от высоты блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы если блок меньше высоты окна страницы(короткое объявление), то футер был бы прижат к нижней части окна браузера, а если блок больше и появляется скролл, то футер бы был сразу под этим блоком?

Comment: Связанные вопросы: «[Как прикрепить футер?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/55480/208074)», «[Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/546490/208074)»

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это просто реализовать с помощью flexbox в роли контейнера:

```js
let cntnt = document.getElementById('content'); 
cntnt.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.innerHTML += '<p>параграф</p>'; 
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#page {
  height: 100vh; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  font: 16px sans-serif; 
  color: #fff; 
}

#page > div, 
#content > p {
  padding: 10px; 
  text-align: center; 
}

#page > div { flex 0 0 auto; }

#content { background-color: #44a; }

#footer {
  margin-top: auto; 
  background-color: #4a4;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="content">кликайте по этому блоку<br>для увеличения его высоты</div>
  <div id="footer">футер</div>
</div>
```

Принцип здесь очень прост:
Вертикальное направление дочерних элементов контейнера задается стилем `flex-direction: column`.
Стиль `flex 0 0 auto` у дочерних блоков "отключает" заполнение ими свободного пространства, и сжатие при увеличении размера "соседей" - но позволяя при этом автоматически подстраиваться под размеры содержимого.
При малой высоте блока контента, футер "прилипает" к нижнему краю за счет `margin-top: auto`.

---

Что можно почитать о flexbox:
[Используем CSS Flexible Boxes (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
[A Complete Guide to Flexbox (CSS-Tricks)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @yar85 хороший, полезный ответ ответ. Кратко, но очень содержательно всё изложено. Кто захочет разобраться в этом вопросе более обстоятельно, получит прекрасную стартовую основу из вашего ответа.

Comment: А ещё можно написать `#page > div:not(#footer) { margin-bottom: auto }`, вместо `#page > div { flex 0 0 auto; }`, тоже будет так работать

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, Да, конечно. Но вообще селекторы будут разные при разной разметке, пример ведь не эталонный.

Comment: @yar85 не подумал об этом, да, с вашим вариантом более гибко