# Как прижать текст к нижней части экрана

Tags: html, css

Как прижать определённый текст снизу-посередине экрана?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
        <div class="text">
            <small class="text-transp">
                texttest - 
                <a href="#">link</a>
                - texttest
            </small>
        </div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопросов [Стили футера в зависимости от высоты блока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806807/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0) и [Как прижать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов достаточно, вы можете обернуть элемент `.text` внутри элемента-контейнера, к примеру, `footer`, контейнер прижать к низу `body`, а `.text` сделать flex-контейнером, в котором элементы расположены в самом низу и в центре по горизонтали:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <footer>
    <div class="text">
      <small class="text-transp">
          texttest - 
          <a href="#">link</a>
          - texttest
      </small>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```